# Error while deploying WSP through SP 2010 Management Shell

Tags: powershell, solution-package

I am trying to deploy a wsp through SP 2010 Mgmt Shell but every time it throws an error:

[image]

This is the script that I am running:

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "E:\QD Survey 2013-01-10\QDSurvey.wsp"
```

Comment: Can you please share the error message?

Comment: Make sure the file is not read-only or you have run Powershell as "Run as administrator"

Comment: Arsalan, The file is not read-only and I checked using both situations, running PowerShell as administrator and the other time without running as administrator but still the same error.

Comment: Does the solution deploy using stsadm. stsadm.exe -o addsolution -filename E:\QD Survey 2013-01-10\QDSurvey.wsp

Comment: Nadeem, same error after running stsadm.exe script

Comment: Should I reset IIS and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolved the error on my own. I checked my Event Viewer logs and found these errors occurring multiple times:

> Event ID: 7031 "The SharePoint 2010 Timer service terminated
>   unexpectedly.  It has done this 34076 time(s).  The following
>   corrective action will be taken in 30000 milliseconds: Restart the
>   service."
>
> Event ID: 7024 "The SharePoint 2010 Timer service terminated with
>   service-specific error %%-2147467259."

This seems that SharePoint Timer Service was crashing after every minute. This was somehow affecting my wsp deployment.

I followed the below steps to fix the timer service issue first and then eventually I was successful in deploying my wsp to the server:

1. Open the Registry Editor
2. Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Shared Tools > Web Server Extensions > 14.0 > Secure > ConfigDB
3. Copy the value in the property "Id"
4. Browse to folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config and create a folder with the name of the previously copied value.
5. Restart the SharePoint Timer service

The folder should be populated with XML files within a minute.

After this my wsp was successfully deployed via SharePoint 2010 Management Shell using Add-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution commands.